# Problem when pause test subscription using Play Billing Library

Tags: android, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I am using Google Play Billing Library 2.0.3

I am working on subscription. I successful subscribe with test account. But I have a problem when I pause subscription. Step to reproduce:

1. In application I subscribe and `acknowledgePurchase`
2. In Play Store App, on subscription page I click pause subscription and choose test period 15 min
3. Back to application. In pause period  `billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)` returned the paused subscription. Is this ok? 
   When I try to acknowledge that Purchase I receive `billingResult.responseCode = 5 (DEVELOPER_ERROR)` with debugMessage "Item is not owned by the user." 
   The same thing happen after pause period, even though my subscription  has renewed.

Is this behavior ok?  Because on the image below we can see that in pause period billing library should not returned paused subscription.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: I can't see anything in your link, make it visible @Vartan Narek

Comment: I use BillingClient v3.0.0 but unfortunately paused items still return in PurchasesResult.getPurchasesList(). Expiry time could be the only difference between active and paused items but this information is only available via server API. I think currently there is no way to detect paused state on client-side (or I missed something). :/

Comment: For paused subscriptions, you will get the subscription in PurchasesResult.getPurchasesList() till the subscription period is over. After that that period, the list will return empty.